# How to import files in another folder using __import__?

Tags: macos, python-2.7

Good morning.

I'm having the following problem: I had a serie of files in the same folder, including a file named 'handles.py' and 3 files named 'module_{number}.py' where {number} goes from a to c.

I was importing the files named 'module...py' from 'handles.py' the next way:

```
def carga_modulos(folder = os.getcwd()):

  files   = [e[:-3] for e in os.listdir(folder) if ((e.split('_')[0] == 'module') & (e.split('.')[-1] == 'py'))]
  modulos = dict()

  for x in files:
    try:
      modulos[x[7:]] = __import__(x)
      print('Cargado módulo {}.'.format(x))

    except:
      print('Fallo al importar {}.'.format(x))

  if len(modulos) == 0:
    print('No se ha cargado ningún módulo.')
    sys.exit()

  return modulos
```

This code works perfectly, however, I've reordered the folder structure of my files and now I've 2 different folders: 'general_files', which includes 'handles.py', and 'modules', which includes the three modules 'modules...py'.

Currently, I'm substituted the previous code by:

```
def carga_modulos(folder = '../modules'):

  files   = [e[:-3] for e in os.listdir(folder) if ((e.split('_')[0] == 'module') & (e.split('.')[-1] == 'py'))]
  modulos = dict()

  for x in files:
    try:
      modulos[x[7:]] = __import__(os.path.join(folder, x))
      print('Cargado módulo {}.'.format(x))

    except:
      print('Fallo al importar {}.'.format(x))

  if len(modulos) == 0:
    print('No se ha cargado ningún módulo.')
    sys.exit()

  return modulos
```

but this doesn't work, the code just falls in except block, failing always in `modulos[x[7:]] = __import__(os.path.join(folder, x))`.

Thanks you very much in advance!

EDIT:

I think I can be more clear: what I want to replicate will be the following code

```
import sys 
sys.path.append('../general_files')

import module_a
import module_b
import module_c
```

The idea is to not need to change the code if I add a new file to the folder called 'module_d.py'.

Comment: Fails how? Show the traceback please

Comment: `*** ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.`

Comment: I've edited my code @MadPhysicist